# Background video not playing on Safari Browser on Mac

Tags: html, video-streaming

I have a hero background looping video on our main page. I also set up a static image for mobile devices. I plays on all browsers except safari on a mac. When I try and paste in the direct url I get a play symbol with a line through it. Has anyone else seen this issue?

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://getclients.com/assets/video/b-roll-website720-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for other browsers

*{

background: #zzzzzz;

}

Answer (score 0):

When I re-encode your video, it plays fine on Safari:
https://cdn.api.video/vod/vi5MqSV9ma8vkT6gy4Z56Kue/mp4/720/source.mp4

I would re-encode (or just download the video above), and try again.

I didn't see anything obvious about the encoding, but Safari didn't like something :)